# How to remove commas and parenthesis from a csv

Tags: python, csv

I am parsing through a pdf and finding the names of locations (Cities and Countries) then finding the longitude and latitude of those locations and saving that information to a csv and using that csv to make a global heat map to see where the cities are located that are in the pdf. The issue I am having is my latitude and longitude are saved in this format "(lat,lon)" which saves them in  a single column in the csv. I am trying to get rid of the comma and parenthesis from the so it will split them into two separate columns. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
doc = open("/home/hank/Work/plotting-named-entities-in-python/text.txt",encoding="utf8").read()
places = GeoText(doc) #Uncomment out if you want to do a text file
cities = list(places.cities)

geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=2)

lat_lon = []
for city in cities: 
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(city)
        if location:
            #print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            lat_lon.append(location)
    except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
        print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s"%
             (city, e))
pd.DataFrame(lat_lon).to_csv("/home/hank/Work/file.csv", header=None,index=False)
```

Where it is parsing the file then finding the latitude and longitude then finally saving all this data to a pdf.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _my latitude and longitude are saved in this format "(lat,lon)"_ Is the data simply being stored as a tuple in the datafame? If that is the case, all you need is to split it into two columns then, not after it's been written to CSV.

Comment: @AMC It is being stored as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a pd.DataFrame out of your list:

```
lat = [i[0] for i in lat_lon]
lon = [i[1] for i in lat_lon]
data = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
df_lat_lon = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_lat_lon.to_csv("/home/hank/Work/file.csv", header=None,index=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is giving me the same exact csv as before.

Comment: So as it turns out, this was working but I was checking the wrong updated csv file. Sorry about that and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The location variable is holding a geocode object. [Documentation here](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.geocoders)

To get the latitude and longitude from the string stored in the object, use:

```
lat = location.latitude
long = location.longitude
```